# Vim Taglist: how to jump to function/variable in standard c library?

Tags: vim

I am not sure if it is possible that to jump to functions/variables in standard c library.

CTags and Taglist are installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a *tags database* for the standard C library (with `ctags`), just as you would for your own source code. Then, include the path to that `tags` file in the `'tags'` option, so that Vim considers it.

The *TagList* plugin is only concerned about showing tags for the *current* buffer.